# Relative paths when uploading image with Symfony 1.4 on shared hosting

Tags: symfony-1.4, shared-hosting

I've had a running website on VPS which I've built using Symfony 1.4.20 but then I decided to move it to a shared hosting and the problems arised. I think I've done the essential parts since it's accesible now but when I try to upload any images via backend it shows error message as in the ss below:

[Failed to create file upload directory "/../public_html/img".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ7Ce.png)

img folder, which I try to upload the image into, is already created and inside the public_html folder. I also set public_html and img folders' chmod as 777.

When I use the url_for function it shows the correct url of images from public_html/img folder, for example: domain/img/imagename.png

Here's my configuration:

/

/app (Everything except web folder is here)

/public_html (I put everything inside the web folder into this folder)

My ProjectConfiguration.class.php file:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony-1.4.20/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
public function configureDirectories()
{

    sfConfig::set('sf_web_dir', '/../public_html');
    sfConfig::set('sf_all_images_url', '/img');

    sfConfig::set('sf_all_images_dir', sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img');
}
```

And in my backend.php:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
```

So when I want to save any image I give the relative path like this:

```
$filepathImage = sfConfig::get('sf_all_images_dir') . '/' . $filenameImage;
```

It used to work back in the day when my website is configured as default on the private server but now I'm stuck, I need to fix this as soon as possible, so please help me :) I didn't do any url rewriting. If you need further information about any part of the project I can show it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to dump ur $filepathImage and see if it's the right path

Comment: When I print $filepathImage to the screen it's like this: "/../public_html/img/e2707ba0588b8f6648ff8a66c9a48484b4f1d5ea.jpg"